# Convergence of a stochastic process to another?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I wonder if there is a notion of convergence of a stochastic process to another stochastic process. To be precise, I am looking for a theorem like the following,

Let $A_n$ and $B_n$ two stochastic processes with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, if certain conditions hold (this is the part that I am looking for), $\exists$ N for which $n \geq N$ the following holds,

$$P(|A_n - B_n|> 0) <  \epsilon$$

or something like that (may be this is not the unique type of convergence).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the stochastic process $C_n = A_n - B_n$. Any theorem about the convergence of $C_n \to 0$ is equivalent to a result you are asking for.

Comment: thanks! I did not think about this.